# Fraction part in binary representation of floating point numbers

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

When I attempt to convert -0.75 (-1.1 * 2^-1 in binary) to its binary form, I get

```
1 01111110 00000000000000000000001
```

but the number -0.75 in binary is actually

```
1 01111110 10000000000000000000000
```

is there a reason why the "1" is in the leftmost part of the fraction area as opposed to the rightmost?

Comment: It is half plus one quarter, so if the most significant bit is on the left, then you should have the quarter representing bit turned on (the half one is implicit) at the left of the mantissa. As the exponent is palindrome, I cannot tell you which endian this number representation is using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) the decimal *fraction*, corresponding to its 24-bit binary representation, is a sum of **negative** powers of two, and also there is an *implicit bit* at position 24, which is always "1". This implicit bit always adds one to the sum (excluding some special cases - for example, zero).

Examples:

```
000000000000000000000000 = 1 * 2^0 = 1
100000000000000000000000 = 1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^(-1) = 1.5
110000000000000000000000 = 1 * 2^0 + 1 * 2^(-1) + 1 * 2^(-2) = 1.75
```

You can play with amazing online [converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to better understand this standard.